# How to keep outputs of an operation between 2 set values? (limits,modulus)

Tags: math, lua, limit

I would like to write an operation that takes a number, that could take any value larger than -1, and only outputs a number between -1 and 0.5

Currently, I am able to ensure that the above happens and it always outputs a number between 0 and 1 by doing the following:

```
SupressedNumber = (Number)%1
```

And the following for values between -1 and 0:

```
SupressedNumber = (Number)%-1
```

And the following for values between -0.5 and 0:

```
SupressedNumber = (Number)%-0.5
```

However I would like to make it between **-1 and <-0.5 (-0.49ish max)**. It doesn't have to use modulus but I feel like it's part of the solution. It just has to be doable in lua.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used lua, but mathematically it's `1.5 * ((Number)%1) - 1`.

Comment: You say "any value larger than" does include the max value a double can hold? Or is there an upper limit to the input value. Also what is the behavior of the result value range do you need to distinguish the result of input values from each other?

Comment: Is the upper limit 0.5 or -0.5?

Comment: If my answer, solved your problem, consider marking as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you want to clamp a number between two values, but one of them is a [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum), not a maximum. Lets solve the first problem first:

To clamp a number between two values inclusivly (e.g. -1 <= number <= -0.5), you can use the standard lua functions [`math.min()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.max) and [`math.max()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-math.max) or even code it yourself, if you need pure lua:

```lua
local function clamp(min, value, max)
    return math.max(min, math.min(max, value))
end
```

`clamp()` will return value, but if value is smaller than min, it returns min. If it is greater than max, it returns max, so the result never leaves [-1, -0.5].

Since your goal is: [-1, -0.5), you have to make a compromise. Computers store decimals with a finite amount of precision, so you can't get a number that is infinitly close to -0.5, but maybe a number, that is close enaugh. Let's create a variable `epsilon` which says, how close is close enough:

```lua
local epsilon = 0.00001
```

And now we can put both ideas together:

```lua
supressed_number = clamp(-1, number, -0.5 + epsilon)
```

This will clamp your number between -1 and a little bit less than -0.5:
-1 <= value <= −0,49999 < -0.5